# Attention: Something went wrong, Error when applying filter

Tags: magento2, attributes, sales-order, filter, order-grid

I added an attribute in `sales_order`, and display it as a column in `sales_order_grid`, all is set but when I try to `apply filter` on my custom column it gives me an error with a pop-up like: **Attention: Something went wrong**, Yes! I also get some errors in console and in network please see below images:

[image]
[image]
[image]
Here Is my code:
`app/code/EC/SampleModule/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <column name="sample_status" class="EC\SampleModule\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Status">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">EC\SampleModule\Model\Source\printStatus</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">                    
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="bodyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/cells/html</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Sample Status</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

`app/code/EC/SampleModule/Model/Source/printStatus.php`

```
<?php

namespace EC\SampleModule\Model\Source;

class printStatus implements \Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface
{
    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        $options = [
            [
                'value' => 0,
                'label' => __('No')
            ],
            [
                'value' => 1,
                'label' => __('Yes')
            ]
        ];

        return $options;
    }
}
```

`app/code/EC/SampleModule/Ui/Component/Listing/Column/Status`

```
<?php 

namespace EC\SampleModule\Ui\Component\Listing\Column;

use \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use \Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;
use \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;
use \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection;

class Status extends Column
{
    protected $_orderRepository;
    protected $_searchCriteria;
    protected $_resourceConnection;

    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context, 
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory, 
        OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository, 
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $criteria,
        ResourceConnection  $resourceConnection,
        array $components = [], 
        array $data = [])
    {
        $this->_orderRepository = $orderRepository;
        $this->_searchCriteria  = $criteria;
        $this->_resourceConnection = $resourceConnection;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }

    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {  
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as & $item) {
                $order = $this->_orderRepository->get($item['entity_id']);
                $sampleStatus = $order->getSampleStatus();
                $item['sample_status'] = $sampleStatus;
            }
        }

        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue:

`app/code/EC/OrderPrintStatus/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="sales_order_columns">
        <column name="custom_print_status" class="EC\OrderPrintStatus\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\CustomPrintStatus" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/select">
            <settings>
                <filter>select</filter>
                <options class="EC\OrderPrintStatus\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\CustomPrintStatus\Options"/>
                <dataType>select</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Print Status</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

`app/code/EC/OrderPrintStatus/etc/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
     <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
         <arguments>
             <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sales_order_grid_data_source" xsi:type="string">EC\OrderPrintStatus\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection</item>
             </argument>
         </arguments>
     </type>
</config>
```

`app/code/EC/OrderPrintStatus/Model/ResourceModel/Order/Grid/Collection.php`

```
<?php

namespace EC\OrderPrintStatus\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid;

use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection as OriginalCollection;

/**
 * Order grid extended collection
 */
class Collection extends OriginalCollection
{
    protected function _initSelect()
    {
        $this->addFilterToMap('created_at', 'main_table.created_at');
        $this->addFilterToMap('increment_id', 'main_table.increment_id');
        $this->addFilterToMap('base_grand_total', 'main_table.base_grand_total');
        $this->addFilterToMap('grand_total', 'main_table.grand_total');
        $this->addFilterToMap('store_id', 'main_table.store_id');
        $this->addFilterToMap('billing_name', 'main_table.billing_name');
        $this->addFilterToMap('shipping_name', 'main_table.shipping_name');
        $this->addFilterToMap('status', 'main_table.status');
        parent::_initSelect();
    }
     protected function _renderFiltersBefore()
     {
         $joinTable = $this->getTable('sales_order');
         $this->getSelect()->joinLeft($joinTable, 'main_table.entity_id = sales_order.entity_id', ['custom_print_status']);
         parent::_renderFiltersBefore();
     }
}
```